# Tabla vacia imprime None en el navegador con django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, djangorestframework, django-urls

Me pueden ayudar, necesito que la tabla este vacia y no este rellena con None en django en la renderizacion de los templates. Anexo imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código por lo general va como texto dentro de la pregunta y no como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el filtro default_if_none template filter, ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)).

default_if_none mostrará lo que le indiques si la variable que filtras es 'None'.

default mostrará el string si la variable evalúa a False, ej: string vacío, lista vacía, etc

{{ item.somefield|default_if_none:"" }}
{{ item.somefield|default:"" }}